# Ссылка на codepen

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, сниппеты

Если в тексте вопроса присутствует ссылка на codepen, то появляется такое предупреждение

> Ссылки на codepen.io должны сопровождаться кодом. Пожалуйста, выделите весь код 4 отступами с помощью кнопки в панели инструментов или используйте комбинацию CTRL+K на клавиатуре. Для получения дополнительной справки по редактированию нажмите значок [?] на панели инструментов.

Как бы здорово, но почему бы сразу не предлагать использовать сниппет, а не рекомендовать вставлять голый код? Скажем, в такой формулировке

> Ссылки на codepen.io должны сопровождаться кодом. Наш сайт поддерживает вставку и выполнение JavaScript кода. Пожалуйста, нажмите в панели инструментов кнопку `<>` и вставьте ваш код в соответствующие поля. Для получения дополнительной справки по редактированию нажмите значок [?] на панели инструментов.

Ну или любую другую формулировку с призывам использовать сниппеты. В тех пяти процентах случаев когда автор вопроса использует что-то типа TypeScript или SCSS сниппет просто не запустится.

Ну и кроме того, призыва убрать ссылку на codepen нет. Есть призыв дополнить вопрос кодом

Comment: Классное предложение, мне нравится! Ещё лучше -- если бы автоматически читался код по ссылке и сразу распихивался по нужным полям.

Comment: не каждый код из codepen можно вставить в сниппет

Comment: @Grundy Какой нельзя? Там тот же html/css/js

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, больше препроцессоров доступно

Comment: А код может быть например на typescript, которого нет в сниппете.

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо. А если в такой формулировке?

Comment: на мой взгляд слишком большое сообщение и мне кажется его мало кто будет читать, но здесь хотя бы есть вариативность.

Answer (score 9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Codepen предоставляет больше возможностей для написания сниппетов, чем встроенный сниппет. Так, на codepen можно использовать typescript, stylus, haml.

В настоящее время сниппет их не поддерживает. А так как невозможно узнать что использовано в сниппете на codepen, в общем случае нельзя требовать переноса.

Следовательно на данный момент нельзя менять текст сообщения.

Comment: Но 90% вопросов содержат код только на html/css/js. Почему бы авторам не подсказать, что этот код можно вставлять в сниппет?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, откуда статистика? :-)

Comment: Например [вот](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/1157965#resultSets). Количество вопросов по TypeScript составляет 1.5% от общего числа вопросов TypeScript+JavaScript

Comment: еще ограничение на размер на кодепене -1мб, а в сниппете намного меньше

Comment: и о птичках - на кодепен можно сослаться через импорт скрипта

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вы готовы просматривать в вопросе 1мб кода?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov иногда требуется присобачить больше чем лезет в сниппет, ресурсы например

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вот например тут я боролся за размер, лезет в сниппет впритык https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976206/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Еще раз - никто не запрещает использовать codepen. Весь вопрос в локализации одного сообщения, чтобы показать новичкам альтернативный инструмент

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ту я полностью Вас поддерживаю

Comment: Опчтк в кртнк слчилс!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да я потом заметил, но думаю оставить :-)